# Percentage of null values per column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have hundreds of columns in a table and need to assess what the percentage of missing values (null) per column. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: Using "SSMS" here is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some, but alarming from your mechanic.

Comment: "hundreds of columns in a table" mistake number one. That is usually an indication of a badly designed database.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It's pretty clear question to me. What you can do is create a dynamic SQL that does something like: SELECT COUNT(col1) * 1.0 / COUNT(1) AS col1Perc, COUNT(col2) * 1.0 / COUNT(1) AS col2Perc, ... COUNT(colN) * 1.0 / COUNT(1) AS colNPerc FROM yourTable

Comment: To get list of columns for a table, you can check out sys.objects and sys.columns meta views

Comment: @DaleK - there is no such close reason as "showing no research effort" - which is why it isn't in the list of reasons you can select from. The "research effort" is in the downvote tooltip

Comment: Well,i won't argue with the pros, but it doesn't look TOO bad to me, one wants some column statistics in a table. Unfocused question to me is a huge info dump which demands writing a new linkedin clone, or several questions in one. Oh well.

Comment: This is a variation on a common theme to count distinct values, non-blank values and other column statistics using dynamic SQL,  My take on an adapted solution is shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ruDHXSoS).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option that uses a little Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'YourTable'  -- Set Your Table/View Name Here

Select @SQL = 'Select ' +string_agg(concat(quotename(name),' = avg(case when ',QUOTENAME(name),' is null then 1.0 else 0 end) '),',') + ' From '+ @SQL
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select top 1 * From '+@SQL,null,null ) A

Exec(@SQL)
```

Let's assume your table looks like this:

[image]

The Generated SQL will look something like this

```
Select [ID]   = avg(case when [ID] is null then 1.0 else 0 end) 
      ,[Col1] = avg(case when [Col1] is null then 1.0 else 0 end) 
      ,[Col2] = avg(case when [Col2] is null then 1.0 else 0 end) 
      ,[Col3] = avg(case when [Col3] is null then 1.0 else 0 end)  
 From  YourTable
```

The Result would look like this

[image]

If by chance you wanted to UNPIVOT the results

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'YourTable'  -- Set Your Table/View Name Here

Select @SQL = '
Select ColName = [Key]
      ,PctNULL = format(try_convert(float,[Value]),''P2'') 
 From  OPENJSON( (Select ' + (Select string_agg(concat(quotename(name),' = avg(case when ',QUOTENAME(name),' is null then 1.0 else 0 end) '),char(13)+',') 
                               From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select top 1 * From '+@SQL,null,null ) )  + ' 
                   From ' + @SQL + '  
                   For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper 
                  ) 
                )'


Exec(@SQL)
```

The Results would look like this

[image]

Comment: `COUNT(eachColumn) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)` seems far simpler to me. Also why use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` when you can use `sys.columns` directly

Answer (score 1):

"hundreds of columns" is not going to be a good idea. Hopefully this analysis is a step towards restructuring things.

The best way to do this will be to simply generate a query that aggregates all the columns by name.

One more option though is to use XML functionality ([demonstrated with `master..spt_values` below](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1PDPKTo))

```
SELECT      col_name,
            FORMAT(AVG(null_flag ), 'P2') AS NullPct
FROM        master..spt_values t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type ) ca(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT n.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'), 
                    IIF(n.value('@xsi:nil', 'varchar(5)') = 'true', 1e, 0)
             FROM  x.nodes('row/*') n(n) ) ca2(col_name, null_flag)
GROUP BY    col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to do this. You will need to write code that manually checks each item. This in turn can be not only tedious, but tricky because it some contexts there are character limits on the length of your SQL statements, and hundreds of columns could easily push you past that limit.

Typically, hundreds of similar columns is a sign you've made a serious mistake with the schema design, and should instead have an additional table which includes the key from the original table, a column for the sequential/ordinal value relative to the key, and a column for the value. Then add a new row for a repeated column every time you would have set a value in the old table.

If you are not able to change the broken schema, you might instead look at using [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns).

Comment: Maximum batch size is 65536 * 4kb which should keep you going. There are other dynamic limits you are going to hit first, like maxmimum query plan complexity and time to generate plan.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great way to do this, however you can ask the engine for some help:

```
SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCount, ' + STRING_AGG(CAST(
'COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) +')  AS ['+c.name+'cnt], 1-(.0+COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) +'))/(COUNT(*)+.0)  AS ['+c.name+'pctNull] 
' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),', ')+'  FROM '+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(t.name)
  FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
      ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
      ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
 WHERE t.name = 'MyTable'
   AND s.name = 'MySchema'
   GROUP BY s.name, t.name
```

This does not give you your answer, but it does give you some TSQL which gives you a count of all the columns in the table, and a count of each `NON NULL` value for each column.
Be aware that `STRING_AGG` is a **2019** function.

Comment: Minor nit: If you use `QUOTENAME()`, you might as well use it consistently - including for the `c.name+'cnt'` and `c.name+'pctNull'` constructed names. That would allow for weird column names like `x[0]` (quoted as `[x[0]]cnt]` or `[x[0]]pctNull]`).